# Setting up g++ compiler and linker options

Tags: c++, linux, vim, g++

I just recently switched back to Linux from windows and VC, but I never done any special coding using g++ compiler.
Currently my libraries (boost and others) are scattered all over the hard drive and I need to learn how to setup my compiler and linker so that all the compiler settings.. 
(includes, libs, flags) etc..  will be held in one single file or place, so that it becomes easy to manage, because I don't want to type these things every time I launch the compiler on command line.
Also note that I'm using a vim as my code editor and do not want to use IDE.

What is the best way to achieve that goal?

Comment: Do you use any building tools `make`, `CMake`, `autotools`, etc?

Comment: no, I'm not familiar with these tools. just want to build some personal projects on the fly, nothing big.

Comment: you should try to put all your libraries in the same place it will be more convenient. If you need to use a lot of different include directories it's more likely to be a pain for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some of [Building tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software). It's allow you type small command (in `vim` you need just type `:make`) which launch build process with predetermined parameters (includes, libs, etc).

For `C++` in `Linux` the most common tools are:
 - [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29);
 - [automake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake);
 - [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake).
If you use `Qt` also [qmake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake) is available.

I've had experience with all of them and my suggestion is use plain `make` for small projects and `CMake` for others and don't use `autotools` while you don't have to do it.

**Note**: All hight-level tools just help generate appropriate files (`Makefile`) for plain `make` (`CMake` generate `Makefile` based on `CMakeLists.txt`, `automake` based on `Makefile.am`, `qmake` based on `*.pro`).

Comment: Thank for letting me know about make, I think I go and learn how to use it.

Comment: note for Qt: you HAVE to use qmake in the first place if you use any of the macros/language extensions Qt does (like slots and signals)

Comment: @meneldal, Why `HAVE`? [Here](https://github.com/Gluttton/PslRK/blob/master/Tools/CodeManager/Ui/Qt/CMakeLists.txt) is example where I use `Qt` with `CMake`.

Comment: if you don't use any language extensions from Qt you don't need qmake anyway. Maybe CMake has a way to do the same thing. Anyway I was stuck with QtCreator (school) and it wouldn't work without qmake. Maybe it's just their configuration the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
because I don't want to type these things every time I launch the 
compiler on command line.
```

I don't like to type either. All I want to do for small builds is issue:

```
(1) a short alias (2) the name of the file to compile, and (3) an output file.
```

Then I want my tool to take care of all common options, and if necessary, include the paths to any extra -I include directories, -L library directories and form the command line for me.

I have a short script that can handle the drudgery. Separating your projects into separate directories and including a 'bldflags' file with specific options allows the scripts to load any project specific options you may require. It is flexible enough to take any additional options specified on the command line. Alias the script in your .bashrc, and all that is required for quick builds is:

```
g+ filename.cpp outname
```

Now this is a very basic script and is not intented to replace proper build tools for your projects, but for quick compilations, it, or something like it, will sure cut down on the typing required. Here is the short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate input
test -n "$1" && test -n "$2"|| { echo "insufficient input. usage: ${0//*\//} source.cpp out [options]"; exit 1; }

## set standard build flags and test if exists/source ./bldflags
stdclfags="-Wall"             # add any standard flags you use.
test -r ./bldflags && bldflags="`<./bldflags`"

## show build command and call g++
echo -e "building $1 with:\n  g++ $stdclfags -o $2 $1 $bldflags ${@:3}"
g++ $stdclfags -o "$2" "$1" $bldflags ${@:3}

exit 0
```

Make the script executable and include a simple alias in your `.bashrc` giving it any name you like:

```
alias g+='/home/david/scr/utl/bgc++.sh'
```

**Examples of basic use:**  (basic without additional flags or a ./bldflags file)

```
$ g+ input.cpp output
building input.cpp with:
  g++ -Wall -o output input.cpp
```

With a few extra options added on the command line:

```
$ g+ input.cpp output -Wunused -fno-default-inline
building input.cpp with:
  g++ -Wall -o output input.cpp  -Wunused -fno-default-inline
```

Including project specific options in ./bldflags (e.g: `-I/home/david/inc -L/home/david/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/david/lib`

```
g+ input.cpp output -Wunused -fno-default-inline
building input.cpp with:
  g++ -Wall -o output input.cpp -I/home/david/inc -L/home/david/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/david/lib -Wunused -fno-default-inline
```

So to address the `I don't want to type these things every time I launch the 
compiler on command line`, this is a very quick and easy way I've found to cut the typing down to a minimum for quick/repetitive builds where a full `Makefile` isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you David so much for all your effort, but I found a solution so that my source file compiles and runs by pressing a singe F10 button inside vim. see this https://github.com/vim-scripts/SingleCompile maybe you can benefit from this too :)

Comment: That's even better. I primarily write in kate (TDE 3.5.13) and just keep an xterm (konsole) open next to it. kate has similar build options, but I guess I just like entering the build into a terminal. (that being said -- I like to keep the typing to a minimum :)